# Microsoft Print to PDF Driver not listed

Tags: windows-7, print-to-pdf, print-drivers

I have a Windows 7 Pro workstation, which is missing the "Microsoft Print to PDF" printer.

So I used this tutorial to add it back:
https://www.digitaltrends.com/computing/print-pdf-windows/

Sadly, the Microsoft Print to PDF Driver is missing in this list. Windows Update couldn't bring it back and I didn't find any useful information on google regarding this particular problem.

Is there anything else I can do to bring the driver back?
PS: Getting a freeware PDF printer from the internet isn't an option.

Comment: Check the "Microsoft Print to PDF" is checked in Windows features (Control panel - Programs and components - Windows components).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the sentence you provided "So I used this tutorial to add it back: https://www.digitaltrends.com/computing/print-pdf-windows/"

we can see "**But don’t worry: Microsoft did eventually add the feature to Windows 10, and now it should be activated by default**".

As everyone else has said, Windows 7 didn't offer this option.  We'll need to install something (a new version of Office or a third party app) to get this feature. Or, of course, if we really like Windows 10's print to PDF option, we could offer to upgrade them to 10.

If we really had Windows 7, it's more likely that either Adobe Acrobat (not Acrobat Reader) was installed or there was some third-party PDF creator installed at some point.  One of the better free "print to PDF" utilities is CutePDF Writer: 
http://cutepdf.com/Products/CutePDF/writer.asp

We can download it right from Ninite.
https://ninite.com/

Reference:

[Microsoft Print to PDF Printer not showing Windows 7](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-hardware/microsoft-print-to-pdf-printer-not-showing-windows/0da50a66-9684-418c-9517-64f1b909cc4e)

[Microsoft Windows PDF Printer Windows 7](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1665685-microsoft-windows-pdf-printer-windows-7)